# Eloquent many to many to many record attach

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, eloquent, relationship

I have two tables.

```
message - id, title, content

user - id, name
```

I have a pivot table.

```
message_user - message_id, user_id_sender, user_id_receiver
```

A message can be sent by 1-0 (sender can be null) users, defined with **user_id_sender**
A message can be received by 1-N users, defined with **user_id_receiver**

I am trying to define this in Eloquent.

The only solution I have is:

```
class Message
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'User', 
        'message_user', 
        'user_id_sender', 
        'user_id_receiver');
}
```

// Somewhere in the code

```
$message = $this->messageRepository->store($message);

$message->users()->attach($message->id, array(
        'message_id' => $message->id,
        'user_id_sender' => $userSender->id,
        'user_id_receiver' => $userReceiver->id
    ));
```

This is the only solution I could think of, but it feels like a workaround. Is there a proper way to achieve this?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot

Answer (score 0):

You could put into your Message model this:

```
public function betweenUsers($sender, $receiver) {
    return $this->users()->attach($this->id, [
        'message_id' => $this->id,
        'user_id_sender' => $sender->id,
        'user_id_receiver' => $receiver->id,
    ]);
}
```

Then you could somewhere in the code do `$message->betweenUsers($userSender, $userReceiver);`
I understand it is not a exactly what you wanted, but since you are really uncommon kind of pivot table, this is probably sufficient too.